# Git Show/Log: Limit patch size

Tags: git

I want to limit the patch output of `git-show` and/or `git-log --patch`, meaning, that if a commit has a patch longer than X bytes, I don't want to have it returned. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the option `--log-size` is your friend:

> --log-size
>
> ```
> Include a line “log size <number>” in the output for each commit, where <number> is the length of that commit’s message in bytes.
> ```
>
> Intended to speed up tools that read log messages from git log output
>   by allowing them to allocate space in advance.

You then may filter the output by the log size of the commits. You will need a own shell script for that.

Example output:

```
commit 552904c8e49c53a690dc14d848b5517f3995be49
log size 137
Author: XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX <YYYYYYY@ZZZZZZZZZ.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 19 11:31:25 2018 +0200

    asd dziprecowss as diürtproject submodule
```

Comment: That will just indicate the bytesize but still output the log.

Comment: @ErikAigner As I already wrote ... you just may use this information to redirect/filter the output of git log ... there is not such a thing you want ... what should be the use case of such a command?

Comment: The use case is I need to process/index thousands of batches at once, I might want to skip super large ones.

Answer (score 0):

Git commands don't have such options. It's possible to use a bash script:

```
function foolog(){
    SIZE=$1
    for commit in `git log --pretty=%H`;do
      git show $commit --pretty="" | dd |& tail -1 | 
          if [[ `grep -oe '^[0-9]*'` -le $SIZE ]];then
              git show $commit
          fi
    done
}
```

`foolog 1200` prints commits whose size of diff is not bigger than 1200 bytes.